# When can a covering be filtered into an exact one?

Tags: general-topology

Compactness tells us when an infinite covering of a space can be turned into a finite one , but, when is it that we can find a covering which equals the set?

With more symbols: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, let $A \subset X$ , and let $\{\mathcal{A}_i \}$ be a covering of a set $A$ by open sets.

When can I pull out some $\mathcal{A}_i$s such that $ \cup_{\text{index set} } \mathcal{A}_i  = A$?

Comment: I don't understand, how can I take whole covering? If I take whole covering , it can be bigger than the set , right? @Ulli

Comment: A is a subet  of a topological space@Ulli

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have $A \subset \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$? Then consider $J := \{i \in I: A_i \subset A\}$. Then you have $A = \bigcup_{i \in K} A_i$ for some $K \subset I$, if and only if $A \subset \bigcup_{i \in J} A_i$.

Comment: For just this statemtent you don't need that the $A_i$'s are open. And in fact, this holds just for sets. No topology needed.

Comment: I want it to be that it is true for any infinite covering @Ulli

Comment: For a fixed $A$, it only holds for arbitrary coverings, if $A = \emptyset$ or $A = X$: consider the open covering $\{X\}$.